# How to find Implementation of Service by type?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have two services in my application:

```
ServiceA : IService
ServiceB : IService
```

I want to pass `Type` info of service that i need to (`ServiceA` or `ServiceB`) to second class.

Then, i want to grab that service in that second class.

```
IEnumerable<IService> services // i get it from DI by constructor, length = 2
                               // becuase i have two implementations of it
services.FirstOrDefault(x => ... and how to grab for example ServiceA?)
```

So what i should pass to my second class to get the implementation of `IService` of asked `Type`? That services exist in same assembly and i pass list of this services by .NET Core DI Container.

Services and all classes exist in same project but in diffrent namespaces (but they have reference)

EDIT:

Sorry for not clarify this, i need to pass info about object by `string` becuase im sending `JSON` to it. So i need grab some kind of info about `Service` as string, then deserialize it in second class and based on string find proper service from `services` list

EDIT2:

Example, what i want to do:

```
// logic, i know i need ServiceA, pseudocode:

return ServiceB.GetType().ToString();

// then, serialize it to json:

string json = object.Serialize(); // object where i have property for example : "service": "ServiceB"

// second class

public Task Handler(Object input)
{
   // deserialize input;
   // and grab service
   var service = services.FirstOrDefault(x => x .....);
}
```

Comment: Why does the second class need to know the specific implementation of the service?

Comment: Because they doing the same, but they have diffrent input parameters that is crucial `ServiceA` cant compute data that `ServiceB` can, i want to pass to second class info what service is needed to use

Comment: If you are working with interfaces and need data on classes that implement the interface, then you have some design problems you should address. But you can do this LINQ to get your service `service.FirstOrDefault(s => s is ServiceA)`

Comment: @KingOfArrows so what design pattern you recomend when i need to use external service that doing the same (for example, converting file to pdf) but first service cant compute `.docx to .pdf` but second can do it?

Comment: If a class says 'give me an interface so I can call some functions', it doesn't give a damn about what implementations are done for the interface. All it knows is that it's going to be passed objects that have agreed to implement what's in the interface and that it can call those functions. If your class only wants a certain type of implementation, then the class should ask for the class/interface that it needs.

Comment: I feel that you should instead have this class ask whoever is going to use it to provide them with an IDocxToPdf (which is an interface that has a function that will convert a docx to a pdf ) and have ServiceA implement that interface and pass serviceA to the class.

Comment: But its good to know what service i need to use. If i have class named `Convert` that converts file type to asked file type i dont want to hard-code the `SerivceA` and `ServiceB`. I want to find the solution that `Convert` class can grab service that he need to use by input parameter. For more clarity, i have 10 types that can be saved to 15 types that can compute only ServiceA and another 5 types that can be saved to 10 types and only ServiceB can do it. Its not my code but im using third-party dlls so i looking fo walk around. I want to have simple class `Convert` to o conversion

Comment: So the Convert class will have an IEnumerable of IService and it has a function to convert from docx to pdf? I suggest to remove the IEnumerable of IService and replace it with concrete instances of ServiceA and ServiceB. That way when Convert.FromDocxToPdf is run, you can go isntanceOfClassA.ConvertFromDocxToPdf. I don't think this using interfaces in the best way. They are meant for when anything that implements the interface is perfectly fine to use because all you want to do is call the methods in the interface.

Comment: I agree with @KingOfArrows. Your essentially losing some key benefits of using interfaces if at the point of actually implementing the functionality you need to know the specific service type. An interface is a contract that you should be able to work against without specific limitations. It shouldn't only work in some cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the type of the object, which is done by `x.GetType()` and compare it against the ServiceA type (`typeof(ServiceA)`).

[LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) example (just copy+paste into LinqPad):

```
void Main()
{
    IEnumerable<IService> services = new List<IService>() { new ServiceA(),
                                                            new ServiceB() };
    var service = services.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType()==typeof(ServiceA));
    service.Dump();
}


class ServiceA : IService { }
class ServiceB : IService { }
interface IService { }
```

[**Run it in .NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kTdpSu)

Alternatively, you can also use `service.GetType().Name` to get the type name as string, and then match the string, i.e.

```
string strService = "ServiceA";
var service = services.FirstOrDefault(x => GetType().Name==strService);
```

If you have different namespaces, you might need to add `using` statements, or do a fully-qualified reference of `ServiceA`.

Comment: Exactly. You can also simplify the LINQ part by using 'is'.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for not clarify this, but what if i need to pass parameter to second class as `string`? Instead of `typeof` can i use `nameof`? For example, in first class i want to return `nameof(ServiceA)` and then do the same in second class by searching by class name?

Comment: @michasaucer String to Type is not had either use GetType(string fullySpecifiedName) or have a dictionary<string, iservice> so you can map userfriendly string to a type easly

Comment: @michasaucer - Not quite clear what you mean, can you add a code sample to your question (even if it does not work currently, something demonstrating what you want to do)? The comment **Drag and Drop** made already suggests how to use a dictionary to find the proper object.

Comment: @michasaucer - I have also edited my answer, is that what you need?